# Swift 4 - UIProgressView coming up as UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uiprogressview

Putting a ProgressView into a ViewController.

When I drag the ProgressView over to create an outlet the option comes up as UIView and not UIProgressView. What am I doing wrong?

Using Swift 4/Xcode 10.2.1

[image: UIView only option in dropdown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to say it but you must be dragging the wrong view. Just added a Progress View to a project and control + dragged it across and got this:

[image]

It's easier to control + drag specific views from the left hand side navigator sometimes instead of directly from the story board.

Edit: Other than that I would try removing it and adding it again and/or restarting Xcode.

Comment: Control + the left side navigator works. From the view and the ProgressBar is highlighted gave the UIView only. Many thanks.